# Usage of aliases in OVER() clause

Tags: postgresql, row-number

May i number results via `row_number() OVER()` by **counted** rows?

e.g.

```
SELECT *,
    users::numeric/population::numeric*100 AS penetration,
    row_number() OVER(ORDER BY penetration DESC)
FROM states ORDER BY penetration DESC
```

generates an error:

```
ERROR: column "penetration" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do that in postgresql. Look for `expression` here:[4.2.8. Window Function Calls](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS), it says ***..it cannot be output-column names or numbers..***

You can user subquery:

```
SELECT states.*, penetration, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY penetration DESC)
  FROM states
  JOIN (SELECT id, users::numeric/population::numeric*100 AS penetration
          FROM states) s_pen on spen.id = states.id
 ORDER BY s_pen.penetration DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use postgre but for t-sql you have to do something like this:

```
SELECT *,
    penetration,
    row_number() OVER(ORDER BY penetration DESC)
FROM 
(
   select users::numeric/population::numeric*100 AS penetration
   from states
)pen
 ORDER BY penetration DESC
```